# Unable to deploy LWC from VSCode

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, vs-code

Apex is getting deployed but on coming to LWC VSCode is throwing error:

```
force-app\main\default\lwc\#######\#####.js-meta.xml  Failed to save Lightning Component Resource [lwc/#######\#####.js] of Lightning Component Bundle [#########]. Error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION         
force-app\main\default\lwc\#######\#####.js-meta.xml  Failed to save Lightning Component Resource [lwc/#######\#####.js-meta.xml] of Lightning Component Bundle [#########]. Error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION
force-app\main\default\lwc\#######\#####.js-meta.xml  Failed to save Lightning Component Resource [lwc/#######\#####.html] of Lightning Component Bundle [#########]. Error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION
```

Comment: As exception is UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION so we need to see the code what is wrong in that, so would you mind sharing the code as well.

Comment: Hey it got fixed.After sandbox refresh my profile was changed from sys admin.After getting back the profile it got deployed.